# can I define my own panel control with asp.net usercontrols

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, panel, contentcontrol

I want something like that:

```
<my:MyFancyPanel>
   <asp:Label Text="Hello">
</my:MyFancyPanel>
```

I tried but it seems my usercontrol doesn't accept any content.

Comment: im just curious, what is the reason for wanting this? if all your doing is nesting other controls/html in it, is a regular asp:panel not sufficient? You could always create a Custom Control (instead of a Server Control) inheriting from the Panel class. But of course then you dont have markup, you'll have to add controls from code-behind.

Comment: I want to create a panel with scrolling and border and so on. But this panel should be used in serveral places so it alway gets different content in different places.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to make it a [Templated Usercontrol](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36574bf6.aspx)

Comment: Looks great. Is there a way to get User Controls into the Toolbox?

Comment: Never done that, but you can try the ToolboxItemAttribute: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.toolboxitemattribute.aspx ;)